# How can I inspect element like in Firebug via JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, yui, firebug, javascript, inspect

I need to have a user poke at an element on a website, almost exactly like with Firebug as a developer. Does anyone know a simple way to do this in JavaScript, or a library like YUI or jQuery?

Comment: The user doesn't want to install firebug? Maybe this would do the trick? http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 1):

with jquery

```
$("*").click(function(e){

    // do something (eg: console.log(this);)

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​
```